# Getting two hours more than required

Tags: php

I am getting times in format of "hh:mm:ss".
I am doing sum of all those times. But here I am getting two hours more than required. so, where is the actual problem.
My code is like,

```
foreach($result as $key=>$value)
{
    $total_markin_time[] = date('H:i:s',  strtotime($value['clock_in']));
}
```

Getting result like,

```
00:33:41
16:15:22
11:06:59
11:03:59
11:13:38
15:43:34
11:29:35

foreach ( $total_markin_time as $time )
                {
                    list( $g, $i, $s ) = explode( ':', $time );
                    //echo $g."-";
                    $total_markin_seconds += $g * 60 * 60;
                    $total_markin_seconds += $i * 60;
                    $total_markin_seconds += $s;
                }

                //echo $total_markin_seconds; exit;

                $total_markin_hours    = floor( $total_markin_seconds / 3600 );
                $total_markin_seconds -= $total_markin_hours * 3600;
                $total_markin_minutes  = floor( $total_markin_seconds / 60 );
                $total_markin_seconds -= $total_markin_minutes * 60;
```

When I am doing sum on this, I am gettin result `77:26:48`.
Where is the problem?
**Updated:**
Is there any problem with `floor` that I have read like,

```
The floor() function rounds a number DOWN to the nearest integer, if necessary.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no error and it works right.
Calculation:
hours: 0+16+11+11+11+15+11 = 75 hours
minutes: 33+15+6+3+13+43+29 = 142 = 2 hours and 22 minutes
seconds: 41+22+59+59+38+34+35 = 288 = 4 minutes and 48 seconds
The result of sum is 77:26:48.

If you want to get just the sum of hours you should use something like this

```
foreach ( $total_markin_time as $time )
                {
                    list( $g, $i, $s ) = explode( ':', $time );
                    $total_markin_hours += $g;
                }
```

Comment: Should we not put $g * 60 * 60 four hour?

Comment: @ViralBhoot If you need just sum of hours it is not nessesary for you to convert hours to seconds. It is nessesary if you need to consider minutes and second while converting.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple. All your times adds to:

```
288 s = 4m 48s
142 m = 2h 22m
75 h
```

Which in result (add hours + minutes + seconds) gives 77:26:48

You may think that You only add hours independent of minutes and seconds, but You have to add overflows of minutes and seconds.

Comment: Thanks @Sylwester: But how can I get this?
I just stuck in that so.